# How to create a two column table, with different amount of rows for each column - latex Overleaf

Tags: tables, multirow

I am trying to create a table similar to the one I am attaching. It has two columns, but the rows per column are different.

I am trying to use multicolumn and multirow but until now I have simply created a mess.[image: Table I would like to have]

```
\begin{table}[h]
\small
  \caption{Features for the creation of a microfluidic platform. Table adapted from \cite{VanDenBerg2010}.}
  \label{tbl:buffer}
  \begin{tabular*}{0.80\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
    \hline
    Microfluidic unit operations & Fabrication technology \\
    \hline\\
    \multirow{5}{*}{Fluid transport  Fluid metering  Fluid  valving   Fluid mixing   Separation} & \multicolumn{1}{m{6cm}}{Validated manufacturing technology for the whole set of fluidic unit operations (prototyping and mass fabrication} \\

   \hline
  \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Why don't you use an itemize environment within the second row (one per column)?

Comment: I am not really interested in having the "dots" before the word, simply to have 8 rows in the first column and 2 rows in the second one..

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are interested in a result like the following (without bullet points):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\small
  \caption{Features for the creation of a microfluidic platform. Table adapted from \cite{VanDenBerg2010}.}
  \label{tbl:buffer}
  \begin{tabularx}{0.80\textwidth}{p{4cm}X}
    \toprule
    Microfluidic unit operations & Fabrication technology \\
    \midrule
    Fluid transport  \newline 
    Fluid metering  \newline 
    Fluid  valving  \newline 
    Fluid mixing   \newline 
    Separation 
    & Validated manufacturing technology for the whole set of fluidic unit operations (prototyping and mass fabrication) \\ \addlinespace
    Accumulation/amplification \newline 
    Reagent storage \& release \newline
    Incubation \newline
    ...
    & Seamless integration of different elements \newline 
    ... preferable in a monolithic way \newline
    ... or by a well defined easy packaging technique\\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In order to allow for automated line breaks in table cells, I used a `p` type and an `X` type column. The latter is introduced by the `tabularx` package and exactly occupies the width of the whole table minus the widths of the other columns. For manual linebreaks in table cells, I have used `\newline`. I have also replaced the `\hline` commands by the rules from the `booktabs` package in oder to have some more white space around them.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to continue using the multirow and multicolumn approach: It looks like you've just misunderstood where `\multirow` and `\multicolumn` should be applied: I think you tried to use them opposite where they should be (and in this case you only need `\multirow`).

`\multirow` is for creating a cell that spans across multiple natural table rows, and `\multicolumn` is for creating a cell that spans across multiple natural table columns.

So it looks like you probably want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\abovetopsep=0.4ex % separate the top rule from the caption a bit

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Features for the creation of a microfluidic platform. }
  \label{tbl:buffer}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    Microfluidic unit operations & Fabrication technology \\
    \midrule
    Fluid transport   & \multirow[t]{5}{6cm}{Validated manufacturing technology for the whole set of fluidic unit operations (prototyping and mass fabrication)} \\
    Fluid metering  \\
    Fluid  valving   \\
    Fluid mixing   \\
    Separation \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]